# rest api headers for CSV downolad

Tags: rest, encoding

I am trying to download a csv file with an Http request with Microsoft Power Automate (Http Action)

When downloading the CSV file using the browser (Chrome) it gets saved without issues.
I have tried to replicate the request performed by the browser by copying it from the Chrome DEv Tools into Postman but the output I get is always full of � instead of accents and other special charaters.

Below the request copied from the browser (working):

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=it_IT; _pk_id.VgqPAYv02a.8cd9=0e06176adbe1b814.1679491263.3.1679744616.1679737532.
Host: www.aifa.gov.it
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 24 Mar 2023 10:32:50 GMT
Referer: -----xxx------
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

I have tried changing to different encoding, but still no luck, if I open the file downloaded by the browser and open it with NOtepad++ he says that the encoding is ANSI but that does not work too in my request.

Is there anything else I can try?
What am I missing? Shouldn't the same request return the same result or is there something else in the middle that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can download by clicking `Send and Download` button in Postman instead click the `Send` button.

[image]

This is an examples CSV URL from `https://www.aifa.gov.it`.

```
https://www.aifa.gov.it/documents/20142/1804956/CDA_2019-2024_24.03.2023.csv
https://www.aifa.gov.it/documents/20142/1805745/Registri_PT_attivi_24.03.2023.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that.
Actually if I download the file this way the characters look correct.
My problem is probably in the creation step and not in the downloading as I first supposed.
I will lokk into how power automate saves the csv to see if I can fix it.